# Require BeautifulSoup in a Python Package - What's needed in setup.py?

Tags: python, module, distutils, python-2.7, setup.py

I'm writing a setup script for a python distribution, `foo`. My code requires `BeautifulSoup`, so currently my directory is structured like so:

```
<root>/
        setup.py
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        BeautifulSoup/
            __init__.py
            BeautifulSoup.py
            etc.
```

And setup.py currently looks like this (less meta info):

```
setup(name='foo',
      version='0.9.0',
      py_modules=['foo']
      )
```

I want to include `BeautifulSoup` in case the user doesn't have it installed already, but I also don't want to install it if they already have it installed at a particular version. I noticed in the [Python 2.7.2 docs](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html) that I should included `packages=[...]` in my setup.py file.

However, [Section 2.4. Relationships between Distributions and Packages](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages) mentions that there's a way to specify that a particular version of the package is required. I couldn't find any examples of how to use a "requires expression" within setup.py, so I'm not sure if this is what I need.

In short, I need a way to say:

> This package requires `BeautifulSoup`, with at least X.X.X version. If that version isn't installed, use the one that's provided.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directory structure:

```
<root>/
        setup.py
        foo.py
```

Note: there is no `__init__.py` file.

You could use [`distribute`](http://packages.python.org/distribute/) to specify dependencies, `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='foo',
      version='0.9.0',
      py_modules=['foo'],
      install_requires=['BeautifulSoup >= X.X.X'],
)
```

This will install required version of `BeautifulSoup` if it is not already present. You don't need to provide `BeautifulSoup` in this case.

If you don't want to install `BeautifulSoup` automatically:

```
<root>/
        setup.py
        foobar/
            __init__.py
            foo.py
            BeautifulSoup/
                __init__.py
                BeautifulSoup.py
                etc.
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='foobar',
      version='0.9.0',
      packages=find_packages(),
) #NOTE: no install_requires
```

Somewhere in in your modules:

```
import pkg_resources
try:
    pkg_resources.require("BeautifulSoup>=X.X.X")
except pkg_resources.ResolutionError:
    from foobar import BeautifulSoup
else:
    import BeautifulSoup
```

It is a less desirable and unusual method.

Comment: since `__init__.py` is there, how would I change my setup script?